# Alignment of captions in subcaption

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption

I am using subcaption and want to have the following effect. I want the main figure to contain several subfigures. I want the subfigures to have captions that only come from the \caption{} tag, i.e. I do not want any numbers like (1) or (a) before the captions. My code for the figure is as follows.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
 \centering
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{1.5cm}
    \def\svgwidth{1.2cm}
    \input{subgoal1.pdf_tex}
    \caption{55}
   \end{subfigure}
   \caption{Subgoals employed in the solution of the 8-puzzle}
\end{figure}
```

The problem is that the captions do not appear at the centre of the subfigure, but there is whitespace indent added before the number 55. I want to get rid of this.

I set up my captions in the following way.

```
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{r-parens}{}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{ }
\captionsetup[sub]{labelformat=r-parens}
```

What do I need to add to get rid of the indent?

The minimum working example is as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=2cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{r-parens}{}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{ }
\captionsetup[sub]{labelformat=r-parens}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{1.5cm}
     \rule{1.2cm}{1.2cm}
     \caption{55}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{1.5cm}
     \rule{1.2cm}{1.2cm}
     \caption{44}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Subgoals employed in the solution of the 8-puzzle}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Providing a full minimum-working-example (MWE), starting with `\documentclass` will help expedite assistance, since it will allow us to recreate your situation with less effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`subfigure` sets up a `minipage`. Hence you need to add `\centering` inside `subfigure` environment also.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{r-parens}{}
%\renewcommand\thesubfigure{}
\captionsetup[sub]{labelformat=empty}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{1.5cm}
     \centering                                      %% <---- here
     \rule{1.2cm}{1.2cm}
     \caption{55}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{1.5cm}
     \centering                                      %% <---- here
     \rule{1.2cm}{1.2cm}
     \caption{44}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Subgoals employed in the solution of the 8-puzzle}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]